# How to convert or rewrite Access IIF Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I thought the IIf statements returns one value if the condtion is true or false BUT This IIf statement in Access returns the field and it values.

```
IIf([A1]![KPr],[A1]![Kat],IIf([Data2]![Kat],[Data2]![Kat],[Data1]![Kat])),
```

the table left join in the from clause 
I'm try to realize this statement in `SQL Server` using `CASE WHEN` but it also accepts a true or false condition.

How can I understand and realize this statement.

Comment: iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false ).. In the above statement, they are checking one more condition if first condition fails.. To convert this to sql server check nested case when

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIf function in VB, VBA, and Access is the same as  ps_prakash02 wrote in the comment: `iif(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. this means that if the condition evaluates to true, the `value_if_true` is returned, otherwise `value_if_false` returns.
So a translation of IIf to t-sql is simply `CASE WHEN condition THEN value_if_true ELSE _value_if_false END`.

I'm not so sure what `[A1]![KPr]` means in access, I'm guessing it's KPr column value of table A1 or something like this, so I'll leave them as they are in your question and just replace the `IIF` with `CASE` in my answer:

```
CASE WHEN [A1]![KPr] THEN [A1]![Kat]
     ELSE 
         CASE WHEN [Data2]![Kat] THEN [Data2]![Kat] 
              ELSE [Data1]![Kat]
         END
 END
```

**Note:** [In SQL Server 2012 Microsoft included IIF in t-sql.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)